# I have a problem with the data format by sending data to backend with Axios.post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, server, axios

Please help...
If I send data to the backend as a data set (as in the example below), the server accepts the data without any problems.

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/repair',
        {
            description: 'Descriptiony',
            registrationNo: '8899',
            expire: '2020-12-13',
            startDate: '2020-11-29',
            status: 'Red',
            errorCode: 'e333',
            repairDescription: 'Reparatur',
            spitzName: 'Gumowa Kaczka'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

But if I send data as an object "this.props" then unfortunately I get an error 500 from the server.
Here's code with this.props

```js
continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.props);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/repair', this.props,
        )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(this.props);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
        this.props.nextStep();
    };
```

I tried to view the data using console.log, but it seems to be correct.
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) is Internal Server Error, meaning "that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.". Why are you posting your client side code? You should take a look at why your back end encounters the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your props name:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/repair', this.props.propsName)
```

because props object has several default attributes like children and etc. that can causes the error in backend.

Comment: Exactly that helped. I didn't notice this extension. JSON.stringify is not necessary in my case. Once again, many thanks for such express help.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `Post()`, if an object, gets serialized automatically using `JSON.stringify()` and the `content-type` of the request is set to `application/json`. Make sure that the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/repair` allows this `content-type` in the header since the default might be `text/json`.

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/post

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Dimitri Bret! (I can't comment, that's why I say thanks here). I completely forgot about stringify, and I already read about it. Finally, I was able to see what exactly I am sending to the server and in this form the backend will not accept it. Now I just have to deal with the value of the values. Here's what I send: {"values":{"registrationNo":"1212","startDate":"2021-01-05","expire":"2021-01-15","status":"Red","description":"gggg","errorCode":"gggg","repairDescription":"gggg","spitzName":"gggg"}}

but it schould be:
{"registrationNo":"1212","startDate":"2021-01-05","expire":"2021-01-15","status":"Red","description":"gggg","errorCode":"gggg","repairDescription":"gggg","spitzName":"gggg"}